# CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:3 vs CreatedDate >= LAST_N_MONTHS:3

Tags: soql, query, datetime, time

This might be a silly question... but I'm trying to get the records created within the last 3 months. I have a custom object and I have the following two queries below. I see that the results are very different when I run >= or = and I couldn't put my finger on it. What is the correct usage of the LAST_N_MONTHS against the CreatedDate field in order to get the correct data?

```
SELECT Id
    FROM MyCustomObject__c
    WHERE CreatedDate >= LAST_N_MONTHS:3
```

or

```
SELECT Id
    FROM MyCustomObject__c
    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:3
```

I have a data set like below...

```
Id                  |     CreatedDate
a4b7X0000009h91QAA  |   Dec 17, 2022
```

I am getting the result with CreatedDate >= LAST_N_MONTHS:3, but if I change to CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:3 then the query doesn't return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm):

> To filter for results within a range, use the = comparison operator. To filter for results on either side of a range, use the > or < comparison operators.

Using ">" checks after the end of the range, while "<" checks before the start of the range.
If you include "=" in the comparison with ">" or "<", the range is included too.

For what you want, just check within the range with "=".

However, as noted in the comments, below, you need to make sure you use a range definition that meets your expectations (last 3 months does not include the current month). The same documentation (link above) explains how each possible range is constructed.

Comment: "For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 UTC of the last day of the previous month and continues for the past n months."

Comment: You might need to change the range used.

Comment: Thanks @Phil.... if I am understanding this correctly.... 

If today is 12/27/2022, then CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:3 would give me November 30, 2022 all the way to August 1, 2022. So anything CreatedDate 8/1/2022 to 11/30/2022. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If today is 27th Dec 2022, I would expect the "last three months to be August 1st to November 30th 2022.

Comment: If you need it to be something different, either do not use a range literal and construct your own start/end checks or use a different literal that is more applicable to your scenario.